# How to join a group call with telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to manage my group call with python code.
First I have to join the group call automatically, but What should I put in `InputGroupCall` as parameters?

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client.invoke(functions.phone.JoinGroupCallRequest(
        call=types.InputGroupCall(
            id=0, # What should I put here?
            access_hash=0, # What should I put here?
        ),
        join_as='My_name',
        params=types.DataJSON(
            data='What should I put here?'
        ),
        muted=True,
        video_stopped=True,
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Params is payload for WebRTC part. So you can try to fake it, but you will be disconnected for inactivity (because you need to send audio/video data). The other way is to use WebRTC client for Telegram Group Call to join. After joining you can use another MTProto methods related to Group Calls.

You can find WebRTC client for Telegram here: https://github.com/MarshalX/tgcalls. It works with Telethon and Pyrogram.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.